# reducing the mysql query execution time

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT mt.Test_ID,
       mtp.Test_Plan_Doc_No,
       mp.Group_Name,
       mp.Point_Name,
       mp.Limit_1,
       mp.Limit_2,
       mp.Datatype,
       mt.Start_Date,
       mv.Measurement_Value,
       mv.Status_Value
FROM   measurement_test mt
       INNER JOIN measurement_values mv
               ON mt.Test_ID = mv.Test_ID
       INNER JOIN measurement_point mp
               ON mv.Point_ID = mp.Point_ID
       INNER JOIN measurement_test_plan mtp
               ON mtp.Test_ID = mt.Test_ID
WHERE  mtp.Test_Plan_Doc_No IN ( 'test1', 'test2' )
       AND mp.Group_Name = 'gp_name'
```

hello guys.

The above is the query that i am executing to create a view.

But i have a problem as follows:

the measurement value table has around 82 million rows.
the measurement point table has around say 5 million rows
measurement test plan and measurement test tables have around 9000 - 100000 rows.

My problem is when i execute the above query the execution time is 8 minutes and the result that is generated has only 400 rows.

Is there any possible way to reduce the execution time of the above query?

NOTE : I am using the above query in my web page

Comment: what are the rough duration of execution for the said query?

Comment: have you created necessary indices

Comment: @ianace : its around 8 minutes

Comment: If you run explain on the query does it make use of your indexes? If not, can you now see some to add that will help?

Comment: Please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx` with `xxx` in `(measurement_test, measurement_values, measurement_point, measurement_test_plan)`

Comment: sidenote: if column name of  referenced and reference are similar then u can use `USING(column_name)` instead of `ON t1.column_name = t2.column_name`

Comment: @diEcho i have not used any indices as i not sure of how to use it

Comment: @sankar,It's easy, just create an [`INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for any column used in `WHERE`.

Comment: Try something like `CREATE INDEX Test_ID ON measurement_values(Test_ID)` for all participants of a `JOIN` or a `WHERE`

Answer (score 4):

First off, for an efficient `join`, you should keep the tables in increasing order of number of rows. This reduces the number of row scans drastically. So for your query, the `join` order should be `measurement_test mt natural join measurement_point mp natural join measurement_values mv`. Also ensure that the join columns have indexes defined on them, and they have exactly identical datatypes. `char(15)` and `varchar(15)` are considered similar in MySQL, but not `char(15)` and `varchar(10)`.

Comment: On 2nd thoughts, after going through a lot of other Stackoverflow posts and related articles on internet, I think that the order of the join columns is immaterial. Whatever be the way, it's always going to be a Cartesian product. The indexes and column types have to be taken care of, of course.

Answer (score 2):

reference from you @comment you said u did not create any index on any table. So [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on those column on which are used in **WHERE** and **ON** condition

in your case create index on

```
mt.Test_ID, 
mv.Test_ID, 
mv.Point_ID,
mp.Point_ID, 
mtp.Test_ID ,
mp.group_name ,
mtp.Test_Plan_Doc_No
```

Here I  Rewrite your Query:

```
SELECT mt.Test_ID,
       mtp.Test_Plan_Doc_No,
       mp.Group_Name,
       mp.Point_Name,
       mp.Limit_1,
       mp.Limit_2,
       mp.Datatype,
       mt.Start_Date,
       mv.Measurement_Value,
       mv.Status_Value
FROM   measurement_test mt
       INNER JOIN measurement_values mv USING(Test_ID)            
       INNER JOIN measurement_point mp USING (Point_ID)
       INNER JOIN measurement_test_plan mtp USING(Test_ID)
WHERE  mtp.Test_Plan_Doc_No IN ( 'test1', 'test2' )
       AND mp.Group_Name = 'gp_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper indexes for each column used in the WHERE clause.

You can use a query analyzer to see whether or not the indexes are used.